# How to pass entity_manager from controller to form class as option? error: The required option "entity_manager" is missing

Tags: php, forms, drop-down-menu, symfony4, entitymanager

I am trying to make a dynamic drop-down field in my form. The option in drop-down are fetched from 'name' field of a table. I have created the form using form class and passed entity_manager to form class from my controller.

**FamilyType - form class**

```
namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Family;
use App\Form\AddressType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use App\Entity\Vendor;
//for radio buttons
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TelType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
class FamilyType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $entityManager = $options['entity_manager'];
        $list = $entityManager->getRepository(Vendor::class)->getNameList();
        $arr = [];
        foreach($list as $key=>$value){
            foreach($value as $k=> $v){
                $arr[$v] = $v;
            }
        }


        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, [
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Enter Name',
                ],
            ])
            ->add('contact', TelType::class, [
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Enter COntact number',
                ],
            ])
            ->add('gender', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => $arr,
                'choices_as_values' => true, 'multiple' => false, 'expanded' => true,
            ]
            )
            ->add('address', AddressType::class, [
                //To get validation error for embeded form
                'constraints' => array(new Assert\Valid()),

            ])
            ->add('favorite_food', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices'  => $arr,

            ])
            ->add('Save',SubmitType::class,[
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'btn btn-success '
                ]
            ])
        ;

    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Family::class,
        ]);
        $resolver->setRequired('entity_manager');

    }   
}
```

**FamilyController:**

```
public function familyFoodForm(Request $request)
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $family = new Family();
        $f_form = $this->createForm(FamilyType::class, $family, [
            'entity_manager' => $entityManager,
        ]);        
        $f_form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($f_form->isSubmitted()) {
            if ($f_form->isValid()) {

                $address = $family->getAddress();
                $entityManager->persist($address);
                $entityManager->flush();
                $entityManager->persist($family);
                $entityManager->flush();
                $this->addFlash('success', 'Welcome!! Family is added.');
            }
        }
        return $this->render('family/index.html.twig', [
            'form' => $f_form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

The above code gives me error:
**The required option "entity_manager" is missing.**

I am new to symfony and I have created this by following:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_dependencies.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here AddressType form is embedded to FamilyType, while doing so it is required to pass the 'entity_manager' (as asked in question)  to embedded form class also.

So, In your **FamilyType - form class**

```
->add('address', AddressType::class, [
                //To get validation error for embeded form
                'constraints' => array(new Assert\Valid()),
                'entity_manager' => $options['entity_manager']

            ])
```

Now, entity_manager option is passed to your form. Cheers.